# Why does android Instrumentation test report fail when coverage is enabled?

Tags: android, jacoco, test-coverage

I am trying to generate jacoco reports, but I keep getting an error when I set the testCoverageEnabled property to true.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method $jacocoInit()[Z in class L...
```

Removing the **testCoverageEnabled** property I can run the tests but I can not generate reports.

I am using standard Jacoco configurations. Unit tests and integration tests run properly when run independently.

All online references to this issue seem to be specific configuration issues within projects. Any help is appreciated.

**Update**

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest', 'createDebugCoverageReport']) {

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    executionData = fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", includes: [
            "jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec",
            "outputs/code-coverage/connected/*coverage.ec"
    ])
}
```

Comment: Could you show your jacoco configurations?

Comment: @Artyom, update is in

Comment: What tool version do you use?

Comment: currently using 23.0.3

Comment: I mean jacoco toolVersion.

Comment: jacoco tools : 0.7.5.201505241946